# Different Xml file nodes but one Model class (seri,deseri)

Tags: xml

This is the first xml :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Package xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Answer.xsd">
      <Hood>
        <PackageId>c05e99173462491b82a81256292d56b0</PackageId>
        <ProcessType>3</ProcessType>
      </Hood>
      <AnswerList>
        <Answer>
          <TDCode>000017</TDCode>
          <SurName>kablan</SurName>
          <Name>alican</Name>
          <FatherName>mustafa</FatherName>
        </HacizCevap>
      </AnswerList>
    </Package>
```

The second Xml :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <Package xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Answer.xsd">
          <Hood>
            <PackageId>c05e99173462491b82a81256292d56b0</PackageId>
            <ProcessType>3</ProcessType>
          </Hood>
          <AnswerList>
            <Answer>
              <InstCode>000017</InstCode>
              <SurName>kablan</SurName>
              <Name>alican</Name>
              <FatherName>mustafa</FatherName>
            </HacizCevap>
          </AnswerList>
        </Package>
```

And I have one model class this xml but I need 2 dif property for one TDCODE and for one InstCode.

The problem is I will only one property for this to Code nodes the reason is always one of them is null

Comment: What tech are you using for deserialization? You could have both TDCODE and InstCode as fields and property Code that return value of one of them that is not null.

Comment: yes I use now like that but when tommorow comes and come new XCode what will I do.I can not add properties again and again it's boring and not healthy.In my project I find my code type from lastchild and then go to firstchild and get the name, then can I find the code type then it is usefull.But it is realy boring I dont want the null propertie actually i will hide the propertie which null is in my model class